# grub-legacy not booting default

Tags: debian, grub, grub-legacy

I'm running a Debian server on a hosted service where I have no webbased console access to the computer. I needed to upgrade the installation and also the kernel, but after reboot 2.6 kernel is still used. The server uses `grub-legacy` due to the virtualization platform. `/boot/grub/menu.lst` contains the new kernel, and also `default 0`.

Since I cannot see what happens during boot time I don't know if the boot menu is actually updated. Is there any way I could remotely debug this? I cannot continue the upgrade now because I need to get 3.2 kernel running to be able to install Jessie.

I have run `update-grub` and also installed grub to MBR. It may though be installed on partition as well, I did not setup the system originally.

```
## ## End Default Options ##

title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=1ad904c4-eaf0-4860-86f0-fabfa5df7bc0 ro 
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64

title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64 (single-user mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=1ad904c4-eaf0-4860-86f0-fabfa5df7bc0 ro single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64

title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64 root=UUID=1ad904c4-eaf0-4860-86f0-fabfa5df7bc0 ro 
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64

title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64 (single-user mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64 root=UUID=1ad904c4-eaf0-4860-86f0-fabfa5df7bc0 ro single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.39-bpo.2-amd64

### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
```

I tried [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) but it just prints

```
Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]

Identifying MBRs...

Finished. The results are in the file "RESULTS.txt"
```

and the result file contains nothing useful:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================


============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

no valid partition table found
"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/xvda1       1ad904c4-eaf0-4860-86f0-fabfa5df7bc0   ext3       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/disk/by-uuid/1ad904c4-eaf0-4860-86f0-fabfa5df7bc0 /                        ext3       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=0,data=ordered)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to the virtualization platform XenServer. It apparently does not really use grub but reads the configuration by itself. Not fully verified, but very likely the issue was caused by having also `grub.cfg` file that only contained the older kernel version from `grub-pc`.